# What is the type of In-app purchase used for purchasing cloud storage with no duration

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, cloud-storage

I need to implement a storage subscription in my iOS app using in-app purchase. But unlike normal storage subscriptions, I do not want to add an expiration date or a renewal period for the purchased storage. So that the type is not a subscription.

I'm confused about what to choose from consumable and non-consumable types. The storage gets consumed as the user uploads files into it and the user can buy more storage if needed. But on the other hand, the storage does not actually run out like "number of lives in a game" since the user can delete files and free the space if needed.

What is the type of in‑app purchases that I should use for this?

Comment: Since the storage entitlement can be purchased multiple times, a consumable IAP would seem to be most appropriate.  You will need to track how many units of storage the user has purchased.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you very much. The number of units purchased is tracked in the app. :)

Comment: You would probably want to track it on your server as well or have some way of ensuring that the user doesn't lose their purchases if they re-install the app or move devices

Comment: Yes, the purchase details are added to the database along with the user ID, so it will be possible to keep track of the purchases made by a user. Thanks :)